# How to check value of JsonObject inside JsonArray in Observer Pattern?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit

I want to check each object inside this Array and if its ACTIVE then get data or just keep on checking! I want to collect data of every object that is ACTIVE.

```
@Override
public void onNext(List<PoiListPojo> poiListPojo) {
     for (int i = 0; i < poiListPojo.size(); i++) {
             if (poiListPojo.get(i).getStatus() == "ACTIVE") {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, poiListPojo.get(i).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < poiListPojo.size(); i++) {
            if (poiListPojo.get(i).getStatus().equals("ACTIVE")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, poiListPojo.get(i).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: welcome @Mr.Imposter  you can refer this link for more understanding of the String comparison https://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java